# Automatically substitute a font with an embedded one

Tags: c#, fonts, ms-word

I'm writing a word add-in with C# and in this add-in I'd like to substitute a font with another that I have embedded from the resources.

I know there is a "font substitution" tool in Word which can automatically substitute a non-installed font for another which is installed on the computer. Since this is the exact opposite of what I want to do, I hope there is a way!

Answer (score 0):

Worst case you can manipulate the docx from your AddIn using the OpenXML SDK then reload.

Beware though that if you choose to get your OpenXML package in memory rather than by saving the docx and manipulating that, there is an issue you may run into on large documents.  I'll update this answer when I have the reference handy.

Comment: I don't want to manipulate an existing docx, I want the user to type with one font and the text being written on screen with another one.
the "font substitution" does exactly this but change a non installed fond to an installed one. In my case I want to substitute an installed font with one which is in resources of my add-in.